# Regex pattern print group1 and group2

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm new to using regular expressions here, when I'm trying to extract a content after a string match but the result I'm getting is from Group1

Regex Pattern : `("Method":)(?s)(.*$)`

String:  `I'm a calling a "Method": "Get"`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP8usi/1)

I'm expecting the output to be "Get"

Comment: If you just need one [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), try something like [`"Method":\s*(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/fN9qQ3/1)

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming* that `(?s)` is meant for optional whitespace character, than your RegEx should be as this:

```
("Method":)\s?(.*)$
```

Than `$1` will be matching `"Method":`, but it's quite useless, because content is static.

`$2` matches anything after optional whitespace character. Please note, that capturing group in this case does not match end of line.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/3Xu5Eh/1)

Comment: Instead of using the substitution, can we get the match directly?

Comment: Yes, you can directly access matched groups

Answer (score 0):

You can write it this way:

```
`(?P<firstNamedGroup>"Method"):(?:\s)(?P<secondNamedGroup>.*)$`
```

**(?P"Method")** : It's a named group named **firstNamedGroup** which will capture the pattern **"Method"**
**(?:\s)** : It's a noncapturing group which will match any space character like a space. It's optional. You could write it just like that **\s** instead
**(?P.*)** : It's a named group named **secondNamedGroup** which will capture the pattern **"Get"**
**$** : It's an end of string which will not work as end of line in go. No idea why.
remark:
the **P** of **(?P** is not used in all the regex interpreters.

I assume you are using the go language looking at the config of your regex101 link. By the way, here is the link to the updated version [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aT4vQn/1).

Another version of the regex to match **new line**/**end of line** too could be written like that :

```
`(?P<firstNamedGroup>"Method"):(?:\s)(?P<secondNamedGroup>.*)(?:$|\r?\n)`
```

**(?:$?|\r?\n)** noncapturing group that matches end of string ""$"" or **|** one carriage return or zero **\r?** and a line feed **\n**.
The link to this regex version [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/knpBFZ/1).

And you can use this script example below which shows how to use named groups [go.dev](https://go.dev/play/p/iC1yIIzmWkF). It was generated using ChatGPT because I'm not used in go.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    // Define the input string
    input := `I'm a calling a "Method": "Get"`

    // Define the regular expression pattern with named capturing groups
    pattern := `(?P<firstNamedGroup>"Method"):(?:\s)(?P<secondNamedGroup>"Get")$`

    // Compile the regular expression
    regex := regexp.MustCompile(pattern)

    // Find the first match in the input string
    match := regex.FindStringSubmatch(input)

    // Check if the match was found
    if len(match) > 0 {
        // Create a map to hold the named captures
        captures := make(map[string]string)

        // Extract named captures and store them in the map
        for i, name := range regex.SubexpNames() {
            if i > 0 && i <= len(match) {
                captures[name] = match[i]
            }
        }

        // Print the captured "Method" and "Group"
        fmt.Printf("Method: %s, Group: %s\n", captures["firstNamedGroup"], captures["secondNamedGroup"])
    } else {
        fmt.Println("No match found.")
    }
}
```

I hope it answers your question.